# Is the space $C_0^{k}(\Omega)$ a Montel space?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, topological-vector-spaces

I'm trying to find a reference for the following result:

**Theorem:** Let $\Omega$ be a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $k\geq 0$. Then $C_0^{k}(\Omega)$ it is (not) a (semi-)Montel space.

I tried to find in the classical references, Trèves, Horváth, but without success. The best result I found, it is the the Exercise 34.4 in Trèves book, which ensures that $C^k(\Omega)$ it is not a Montel space. Can we conclude from this exercise the Theorem above?

A proof of this result would also be welcome.